# Elasticsearch Interpreter can not connect to Database

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-zeppelin

I am using Zeppelin version 0.62 installed via Homebrew.

I try to use the Elasticsearch interpreter to connect to a local ES-Instance (Version 2.3.5) which is running locally on port 9209. If I run

```
%elasticsearch
index /test/test/123 {name:"test"}
```

I get:

> None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{127.0.0.1}{localhost/127.0.0.1:9209}]

However, using Shell-Interpreter it works:

```
%sh
curl -XGET localhost:9209
```

I can not find any information with which version the interpreter should be compatible (Also tried against an actual 5.2, same result).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you check that you are using the port for `TransportClient`? (default is 9300)

ElasticSearch supports 2 types of clients but Zeppelin 0.6.2 only supports `TransportClient`. So you have to use port for that. (FYI, Zeppelin 0.7.0 supports both clients)

- [Transport Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/5.x/transport-client.html)
- [REST API Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/5.x/index.html)

See also

- [ElasticSearch port 9200 vs 9300](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-port-9200-or-9300/72080)
- [ElasticSearch Interpreter Doc for Zeppelin 0.6.2](http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.2/interpreter/elasticsearch.html)
- [ElasticSearch Interpreter Doc for Zeppelin 0.7.0](http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/interpreter/elasticsearch.html)

Comment: Thanks for all those Links. I updated to Zeppelin 0.7 and use the HTTP Mode (9200) now.